# Passing a function through props

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i have a function that selects a row of a table, this function is below, it is within my component of SupplierSearchComponent

```
   const handleAddressCheck = item => {
    const itemIndex = supplierAddress.findIndex(supplierItem => supplierItem.id === item.id);
    let newAddresses;
    if (itemIndex >= 0) {
        //the reasoning behind using a filter is that splice will not return an updated array, filter however does
        newAddresses = supplierAddress.filter(x => x.id !== item.id);
    } else {
        newAddresses = [...supplierAddress, item];
    }
    setSupplierAddress(newAddresses);
    props.onSelectAddress(newAddresses);

    console.log('this is the item => ', newAddresses);
};
```

However i also pass this function into another component as

```
  const onSelectedAddressesChange = (addresses) => {
    props.setFieldValue('supplierAddresses', addresses);
};
```

I then pass the value of this into another component as

```
     <SearchSuppliers
       name="supplierSearch"
       label="Supplier Search"
       id="supplierSearch"
       onSelectAddress={onSelectedAddressesChange}
                        />
```

then from search suppliers i pass the prop into the original component of

```
<SupplierSearchComponent
            onSelectAddress={props.onSelectAddress}
        />
```

Now finally within my SupplierSearchComponent i should be able to pass this prop as

```
  <SupplierContactDetails
     onSelectAddress{props.onSelectAddress}
                            />
```

However within my ContactDetails i cannot actually console.log(onSelectAddress) as it will result as undefined, how could i successfully pass this function or rather its result through?

Comment: Could you put this in a jsFiddle please? Will be easier to debug.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you skip "=" when passed props at last component "SupplierContactDetails".

Comment: what do you mean by this?  onSelectAddress= onSelectAddress?

Comment: <SupplierContactDetails
     onSelectAddress={props.onSelectAddress}
                            />